# Minimum amount of water to pressurize pressure cooker

Tags: pressure

What is the minimum amount of water to create enough steam to pressurize a 6qt electric pressure cooker to 11psi( above atmospheric pressure) ?

I am not wanting the recommended volume of water to safely operate a pressure cooker. I am just interested in the scientific equation for how much steam pressure will be created in a certain volume from boiling a certain amount of water.

Another way to put this: Will boiling 1 Tablespoon of water create enough steam to pressurize a 6qt sealed container to 11psi? If not, then how many, or what fraction of, Tablespoons would it take?

Comment: This depends only from the quality of your gaskets. Air is enough to increase pressure inside an insulated system when heated.